# Solve $f(x)' + s x f(x) - r f(x) = 0, \quad f(0) =w$ using stream calculus

Tags: calculus, coalgebras

The ODE $$f(x)' + s x f(x) - r f(x) = 0, \qquad f(0) =w$$ has the solution 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = w\exp\left(r x - \frac{1}{2}s x^2\right).
\end{equation}

I'm trying to obtain this result using Rutten's stream calculus. A key reference for this calculus, containing the identities I refer to below, is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.873.6588&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2878156), trying to work "backwards" from the known solution by seeing if anyone could transform the $\exp(x^2)$ term. What follows is my attempt at working "forwards".

Transform, applying identities 75, 80 and 86
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{T}(f)'+s\times \left[\left(X^2 \times\frac{d\mathcal{T}(f)}{dX}\right)+\left(X\times\mathcal{T}(f)\right)\right] - r\times \mathcal{T}(f)
\end{equation*}
Let $\sigma=\mathcal{T}(f)$ 
\begin{equation*}
\sigma' + s\times\left[\left(X^2\times\frac{d\sigma}{dX}\right)+\left(X\times\sigma\right)\right] - r\times \sigma
\end{equation*}
Set $\frac{d\sigma}{dX}=\sigma'$, this seems natural but I can't find where it is defined explicitly
\begin{equation*}
\sigma'+ s\times\left[\left(X^2\times\sigma'\right)+\left(X\sigma\right)\right] - r\times\sigma
\end{equation*}
**Edit:** As user md2perpe points out below this is in fact wrong. Correct identity is $\frac{d\sigma}{dX}=(X\times\sigma')'$. And seeing as Prof. Rutten is sceptical of a closed form expression involving $\exp(X^2)$ (see comment in the "backwards" question referenced above), I'm not going to invest time in further derivations. I'll leave the original derivation starting from the incorrect premise here for posterity:

Simplify
\begin{equation*}
\sigma'+ s\times X^2\times\sigma'+s\times X\times\sigma - r\times \sigma
\end{equation*}
Drop the `convolution product' notation (I don't think this will get us into trouble)
\begin{equation*}
\sigma' + sX^2\sigma' + sX\sigma - r\sigma
\end{equation*}
Apply the fundamental theorem (4.1)
\begin{equation*}
(\sigma - w)/X + s X^2(\sigma-w)/X + sX\sigma -r\sigma
\end{equation*}
Simplify
\begin{equation*}
(\sigma - w)/X + s X(\sigma-w) + sX\sigma -r\sigma
\end{equation*}
Simplify
\begin{equation*}
\sigma/X - w/X + s X\sigma-sXw + s X\sigma -r\sigma
\end{equation*}
Group
\begin{equation*}
\sigma(1/X +2 s X - r) - w/X + -sXw  
\end{equation*}
Rearrange
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= (w/X + sXw) / (1/X + 2 s X - r) 
\end{equation*}
Simplify (multiply by $X$)
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= \frac{w + sw X^2}{1 - r X + 2 s X^2 }   
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= w \left(\frac{1}{1 - r X + 2 s X^2 }  + \frac{s X^2}{1 - r X + 2 s X^2 }   \right)
\end{equation*}
Using partial fractions and factoring the denominator we get
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= w \left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r + \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 +X} - \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r - \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 + X}  + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{r X }{2 - 2r X + 4 s X^2} - \frac{1}{2 -2r X + 4 s X^2}    \right)
\end{equation*}
Which becomes
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= w \left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r + \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 +X} - \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r - \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 + X}  + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{r X }{1 - r X + 2 s X^2} - \frac{1}{1 -r X + 2 s X^2}  \right)  \right)
\end{equation*}
Then applying partial fractions again with more factoring this becomes
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= \frac{w}{2} \left( \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r + \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 +X} - \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s}}{(r - \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 + X} + \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s} r X}{(r + \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 +X} - \frac{\sqrt{r^2-8s} r X}{(r - \sqrt[]{r^2 - 8s})/2 + X}  + 1 \right)
\end{equation*}
Now let $a=\sqrt{r^2-8s}$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= \frac{w}{2} \left( \frac{2a}{r + a} \left( \frac{1}{1+2(r + a)^{-1} X} +
\frac{r X}{1+2(r + a)^{-1} X} \right)
- \frac{2a}{r - a} \left( \frac{1}{1+2(r - a)^{-1} X } + \frac{r X}{1+2(r - a)^{-1} X} \right) + 1 \right)
\end{equation*}
Back-transform, using identities (82) and (83)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(x)&= w \left[ \frac{a}{r + a} \left( \exp\left(\sqrt[]{2(r + a)^{-1}}x\right) + \frac{\sqrt[]{2(r+a)^{-1}}}{r} \sin\left(\sqrt[]{2(r+a)^{-1}} x\right) \right) \right.\\ - 
&\left. \frac{a}{r - a} \left( \exp\left(\sqrt[]{2(r - a)^{-1}}x\right) + \frac{\sqrt[]{2(r-a)^{-1}}}{r} \sin\left(\sqrt[]{2(r-a)^{-1}} x\right) \right) + 1 \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

This doesn't seem right.

Comment: The formula $\frac{d\sigma}{dX}=\sigma'$ is not correct. According to eq. (61) the definition is $\frac{d\sigma}{dX}=(X \otimes \sigma')'.$